# Typescript Promise and await

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I am working with typescript and trying to get the geolocation of where we currently are. I can get the location, but my code continues without setting the location. I decided to use await and promise. I created a service that looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class GoogleMapsService  {

private latitude: number;
private longitude:number;

public currentLongitude(): number {
    return this.longitude;
}
public currentLatitude(): number {
    return this.latitude;
}

constructor() {
    this.setCurrentLocation();
}

private async setCurrentLocation() {
    let location: GoogleLocation = await this.getLocation();

    this.latitude = location.latitude;
    this.longitude = location.longitude;
}


private getLocation(): Promise<GoogleLocation> {
    let promise = new Promise<GoogleLocation>(() => {
        let location = new GoogleLocation();
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            location.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            location.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        });
        return location;
    });

    return promise;
    }
}
```

so my question is how can I set this while i await it. so when i try to access it it is there?

Comment: `so my question is how can I set this while i await it` - you want to await what?

Comment: let location: GoogleLocation = await this.getLocation();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never resolve your promise in `getLocation`, so naturally `await` will wait forever. Returning a value out of the promise executor *(the function you pass into `new Promise`)* doesn't resolve the promise, and note that what you're trying to return, you're returning [too early](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), before the coordinates are filled in on it.

Instead, accept the `resolve` and `reject` parameters in your promise executor function and use them:

```
private getLocation(): Promise<GoogleLocation> {
    return new Promise<GoogleLocation>((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            if (/*...it didn't work...*/) {
                reject(new Error(/*...*/));
            } else {
                // It worked
                const location = new GoogleLocation();
                location.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                location.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                resolve(location);
                // Maybe you could just `resolve(position.coords)`?
            }
        });
    });
}
```

---

Side note: If you promisify the geolocation service, you wouldn't need `new Promise` in there at all.

Comment: thank you tj, can you suggest a link that I can read up on how to do this?

Comment: @3xGuy: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) tends to be fairly good. [Axel Rauschmayer's blog](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-promises-foundations.html) is pretty good (I notice that it now links to an online book he's done)...